# Gluon netbeans task 'androidRelease' Fail

Tags: java, android, mobile, gluon

Executing: gradle :androidRelease

:compileJava UP-TO-DATE

:compileRetrolambdaMain UP-TO-DATE

:processResources UP-TO-DATE

:classes UP-TO-DATE

:compileAndroidJava UP-TO-DATE

:compileRetrolambdaAndroid SKIPPED

:compileEmbeddedJava UP-TO-DATE

:compileRetrolambdaEmbedded SKIPPED

:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE

:compileRetrolambdaTest SKIPPED

:compileRetrolambda UP-TO-DATE

:mergeClassesIntoJar FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':mergeClassesIntoJar'.

  > Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task 'createSingleJar' during up-to-date check.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 0.404 secs

Build failure (see the Notifications window for stacktrace): gradle :androidRelease

Comment: can you please re-edit your question a bit, hard to read.

Comment: It is impossible for anyone to answer your question: Post the `build.gradle` file, run `gradlew --info androidRelease`, and post any exception you may find, does it works for the `android` task?

Comment: I gave up using gluon. They have terrible support.